# How do I use pipe in a specific exec of a find (in bash)

Tags: bash, find, exec, pipe, md5sum

I have to construct a csv with the output of a shell command; the csv file must contain for each row some information get by the output of stat command and in the last column the md5sum (only the sum without the filename)

I tried some command like:

```
find . -exec stat --printf='"%a";"%F"' {} \; -exec sh -c "md5sum $1 | cut -b-32" {} {} \;
```

but this block and ask me for input

and this,

```
find . -exec stat --printf='"%a";"%F";' {} \; -exec md5sum {} | cut -b-32 \;
```

but in this case the pipe doesn't work.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have `{}` and `;` misplaced. This one is working fine for me on Linux:

```
find . -exec stat --printf='"%a";"%F";' {} \; -exec sh -c "md5sum {} | cut -b-32" \;
```

#### Update 1

You can combine all in one `-exec` option like this also:

```
find . -exec sh -c "stat --printf='\"%a\";\"%F\";' {} && md5sum {} | cut -b-32" \;
```

Comment: the output is wrong: I have to do the cut only on the md5sum, your code do the cut on all the output

Comment: Actually it was your own command, I just fixed the syntax :) But good to know the actual intent, I will rework my answer.